# Why does myForm.$submitted not work with ng-messages but with ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my Form when there is a keypress and also when it its submitted.For that purpose i am writing this code :-

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required/>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.$submitted">
        <span ng-message="required">Please enter details in these field</span>
        <span ng-message="email">Please enter email</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

There is a success message in submit function :-

```
$scope.submit = function(){
   console.log("Update Successful");
}
```

Even if i haven't fill the required field and press Save i still get the "Update Successful" message.So,why doesn't the validation work and why is the submit function even if the validation fails.

Also i found these solution of doing it these way :-

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submit()"  novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required/>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.email.$error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted">
        <span ng-message="required">Please enter details in these field</span>
        <span ng-message="email">Please enter email</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

This works fine but problem is,it should also validated on keypress.However,it only validates on keypress after i have sumbitted the form atleast once before that keypress validation doesn't work.
How should i solve these?
I was also trying myForm.$touched but even that doesn't work when i use it as :-

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.$touched">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you suggest it will submit on keypress? You didn't register the element with a keypress event, right?

Comment: @Dvir No i am not suggesting it will submit on keypress.I am saying that it should validate when there is a keypress or if the form is directly submitted.Also,with the solution i mentioned,the problem is that ,the validation works on submit but not on key-press unless i have submitted the form at least once..and after then it will start working with keypress. Its tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little something that you've missed in implementing *AngularJS*'s form validation.

From the code you've provided, your form, as it seems, is using the default HTML5 form validation and **NOT** AngularJS form validation.

### How?

In order to be able to wire up with AngularJS form validation (technically adding it as a property to the `form` directive), in addition to the `name` attribute of the form control, `ng-model` attribute is also *required*.

Meanwhile, to disable HTML5 default validation behavior, `novalidate` attribute must be added to the form tag.

To be able to achieve your expected behavior from the form (*i.e. validation on key press as well as on submission*, if I'm right) you can implement a combination of `yourForm.$dirty` and `yourForm.$submitted` properties:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.email.$error" ng-if="myForm.$dirty || myForm.$submitted">
    <p ng-message="required">Please enter details in these field</p>
    <p ng-message="email">Please enter email</p>
</div>
```

## [***Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/gnwapeb1/2/)

Comment: Hi Ahmad,Thanks man!.This totally works :) .Sorry that i forgot to add ng-model and novalidate in my example provided here,but i have written it in my actual code. However, just for knowledge purpose,can you tell me why myForm.$submitted doesn't work in ng-messages directly.Something like - ng-messages = "myForm.email.$error || myForm.$submitted" ,Is it that ng-messages doesn't support myForm.$submitted ?

Comment: I don't get your statement _why myForm.$submitted doesn't work in ng-messages directly_. It does work though, but the `$submitted` is set to true _only_ if the form's submit button is clicked (i.e. the form submission is attempted). 

However, if you have something like: 

`ng-if="myForm.email.$error || myForm.$submitted"`, since the `myForm.email.$error` is already defined (_in this case `{required: true}`_) and evaluates to true, you'll still end up in seeing the validation error from the beginning. 

See it in action in this updated [***demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/gnwapeb1/4/)

Comment: Hi ,thanks for these understanding.I tried the demo and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In html:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" required/>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.email.$error" ng-if="myForm.email.$touched || valid">
        ...
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submit(myForm.$valid)">Save</button>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.submit(valid)
{
    valid ? $scope.validCheck = false : $scope.validCheck = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi @DieuNQ , thanks for the solution but i was looking for an approach where i don't have to code anything in controller as i would be making lot of forms and i don't want to perform validation in all of there controllers.